# How to show spectral radius of below $2\times 2$ block matrix is greater than one.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a diagonal matrix $D$ (with sum of diagonal elements be negative), a row-stochastic $W_r$ (right eigenvector $\mathbf{1}$ with eigenvalue 1), and column-stochastic $W_c$ (left eigenvector $\mathbf{1}$ with eigenvalue 1), how to prove that below matarix has spectral radius greater than one? ($W_r$ and $W_c$ are irreducible)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
W_r-D & - I
\\
(W_c-I)D &W_c
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I am pretty sure it is true but cannot prove it. I also ran also many simulations which confirmed my conjecture.

I really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is enough for you, but it is easy to see that the spectral radius is greater than *or equal to* one, and all we need is that $W_r$ is row-stochastic. The matrix has eigenvalue one
$$
\begin{bmatrix}W_r-D & -I\\(W_c-I)D & W_c\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}{\mathbf 1}\\-D{\mathbf 1}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}{\mathbf 1}\\-D{\mathbf 1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the observation. Actually I can show that it has an eigenvalue equal to one, but I need to sow that the spectral radius is strictly larger than one. (I want to show a system has an unstable response)

Comment: Actually this is my main question that I just posted. You be great if you can take a look at it: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2775920/279619